# How do I filter lists, retrieved via async await, in Svelte?

Tags: asynchronous, svelte

I'm using Svelte for the first time, and I'm trying to figure out how to apply filtering to a list retrieved from an API. My EventsIndex component is very simple, and comprises the following logic:

```
import FetchPosts from '../services/postsByType'
import EventCard from '../components/EventCard.svelte'

export let post_type

let events = new FetchPosts( post_type ).get()
let currentCategory = 0

function updateCategory( catId ) {
    currentCategory = catId
}
```

Everything works just as expected.

I'm also using the await template syntax to display the relevant data:

```
{#await events}
    <h1>loading...</h1>
{:then events}
    <section class="grid">
        {#each events as event}
            <EventCard event={event} on:filter={updateCategory}/>
        {/each}
    </section>
{:catch error}
    <p>Something went wrong...</p>
{/await}
```

The missing piece is the reactive filtered list. I *thought* I could do the following, but it generates the error `events.map is not a function`, which makes sense, as the events variable would be an unresolved promise when filteredEvents is invoked.

```
$: filteredEvents = () => {
    if (currentCategory === 0) return events

    return events.filter( event => {
        return event.categories !== null
            ? event.categories.some( cat => cat.id == currentCategory )
            : false
    })
}
```

So how would I add a reactive filteredEvents function, that I can also include in my template?

Comment: Did you try filtering on events inside the each loop?

Comment: @Corrl Could you elaborate? I'm not sure how to go about that...

Comment: @Corrl Never mind, I've found exactly what you mentioned. If you want to include this as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Good it's solved & thanks for accepting! :) I just added an addition concerning the function... not related to the question but thought it might be helpful nevertheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering on the events inside the `{#each}` loop should work. If the filter function was very short like this I'd apply it inline

```
{#each events.filter(e => e.id === currentId) as event}
```

Just as an example. Since in your case the filter function is more complex, moving it to a function might be the better option

```
filterEvents(events, currentCategory) {
    if (currentCategory === 0) return events

    return events.filter( event => {
        return event.categories !== null
            ? event.categories.some( cat => cat.id == currentCategory )
            : false
    })
}
</script>

...

{#each filterEvents(events, currentCategory) as event}
```

(I think you can replace this

```
 return event.categories !== null
            ? event.categories.some( cat => cat.id == currentCategory )
            : false
```

by this

```
event.categories?.some( cat => cat.id === currentCategory )
```

Comment: Many thanks. I switched the refactoring to `event.categories?.some( cat => cat.id == catId )` but otherwise perfect.

Comment: Also perhaps worthy of note, if I shortened it to `{#each filterEvents(events) as event}` the list wouldn't update when the category updated. But it would if I shortened to `{#each filterEvents(currentCategory) as event}`... it seems you need to pass the updated variable as a parameter, perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about the currentCategory changing. In fact it has to be set as parameter so the function is triggered on change, so it has to be `filterEvents(events, currentCategory)` Will adjust the answer, thanks for mentioning! (You maybe don't have to pass the events as parameter, because they are resolved and in scope, when the function is called the first time. But I would do it nevertheless, think it's clearer...)